# Execute code if no string match if found

Tags: javascript, jquery, logic

So this is a logic problem I'm having:

```
$('#id_country').change(function () { // ON CHANGE OF DROP DOWN
    var countryShortCode = $(this).val();
    $('#country-phone-code option').each(function () { //STRING MATCH AGAINST OTHER DROP DOWN
        if ($(this).text() == countryShortCode) { //THE PROBLEM I NEED AN 'ELSE' IF NO STRING MATCH FOUND
            alert("match found"); // (only one match will ever be found, if any)
        }
    });
});
```

What I need to is execute some code if there is no string match. That's what I can't currently do.

i.e.

```
$('#country-phone-code option').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text() == countryShortCode) {
        alert("");
    } else {
        //(if after traversing of each #country-phone-code option, no match was found, do something
    }
```

Apologies for the badly worded question.

Comment: So where is the problem?

Comment: I think a for-loop would better suit your situation than a $.each

Comment: I need to "do something" if no match was found after traversing through "$('#country-phone-code option').each"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#id_country').change(function(){ 
    var countryShortCode = $(this).val();
      var flag = false;
    $('#country-phone-code option').each(function(){ 

       if ($(this).text() == countryShortCode) { 
          flag = true;
          alert("match found"); 
       }

   });
     if(!flag) {

            alert("no match found");
        }

});
```

I think you want this very simple but tricky. use it and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks @Gaurav, exactly what I needed! It was where to put the flag that confuzzled me

Comment: You should put `if(!flag) {` outside each ?

Comment: I have correct the code. I compiled it and then correct. the flag will also be outside and i have done it.

Comment: There's a time limit on accepting answers @Gaurav. You need to wait 10 mins (bit silly really, people often answer it a lot faster than that)